# jQuery OR operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to check if an element has a `data` attribute of either `data-youtube-id` or `data-youtube-id` and run something based on that (basically prevent a link from following through).

How can I check for both attributes at once?

This is what I'm using and it's not working correctly:

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-youtube-id="xxxxxx">link title 1</a>
<a href="#" data-vimeo-id="xxxxxx">link title 2</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('youtube-id, vimeo-id')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I also tried similar jQuery using `attr();` instead of `data();` (also didn't work):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('data-youtube-id, data-vimeo-id')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't believe jQuery has an OR operator, however javascript does, and well jQuery is javascript, so just use `||`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) along with [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if ($(this).is('[data-youtube-id], [data-vimeo-id]')){
}
```

Both [data(string)](http://api.jquery.com/data/) & [attr(string)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) are getter methods which gets the value of said data/attribute value

---

As @Brilliand said you can filter out the elements before you register the click handler.. if this was your complete click handler code

```
$('a').filter('[data-youtube-id], [data-vimeo-id]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why don't data or attr work in booleans then? If they get any data shouldn't they work in an if statement?

Comment: Or use `filter()`, which works on multiple elements at once: `$('a').filter('[data-youtube-id], [data-vimeo-id]').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`... or even `$('a[data-youtube-id], a[data-vimeo-id]')`

Comment: @DannyCooper they doesn't support multiple keys, in that case you need to use `if ($(this).data('youtube-id') || $(this).data('vimeo-id'))` - same with `.attr()` as well

Comment: @Brilliand yes you are right... I really didn't check what was happening after the `if` condition.... too early in the morning I think - 05:30 :(

Comment: @Brilliand I just tried that and it works, but I'm using the link click event for a lot of other things so I'd rather not make a separate click event for filtering.